# C#- Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel copy all rows in excel to another sheet

Tags: c#, vba, visual-studio-2008, office-interop, excel-interop

I have 3-4 excel files in a directory, each excel workbook contains 1 sheet. The structure of each sheet are identical. I want to consolidate all the sheets into one sheet. I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel package in VS 2008. How do I copy all the rows in one worksheet and append at the end of another worksheet? I am new to C# so my question may be improper. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's quite a big question, I'm not sure which specific bits you need help on. I can get the ball rolling with this code

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{ 
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application excel = new Application();
        Workbook wb1 = excel.Workbooks.Open("c:\\temp\\me.xlsx");
        Workbook wb2 = excel.Workbooks.Open("c:\\temp\\you.xlsx");
        Range src = wb1.Sheets["Sheet1"].Range("A1:B3");
        Range dest = wb2.Sheets["Sheet1"].Range("A10");

        src.Copy(dest);
        wb2.Save();
        wb1.Close();
        wb2.Close();
        excel.Quit();
    }
}
}
```

will copy some cells from 'me.xlsx' to 'you.xlsx' (note this is a newer version of VS than you're using)

Does this help?